# Disable Click Event of ListView of Particular Item on which User Clicks

Tags: android, listview

I have `ListView` to display Options of Question. It is like Quiz Android App. Now, I want that when user `clicks` on any option then that Option disables and if user clicks on it again, It does not do any action. Because on Option `click`, I am displaying message to user like whether it is right or wrong option.
I don't want to re-enable it. And I am using `SimpleAdapter` to bind ListView.

Comment: try below solution and let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: so list item contains 3 buttons right? include code if possible

Comment: @InnocentKiller, I am trying your solution.

Comment: @Sishin, It is custom ListView so it contains 4 TextView.

Comment: Okay, Try and let me know if you face ant problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override `isEnabled()` in your adapter. For reference check  [areAllItemsEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled%28%29) and [isEnabled(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29).

So basically `areAllItemsEnabled()` will return `true` if all items are enabled, `false` otherwise.

Comment: I want to disable click after Click on Item. By using this with Adapter, It is disabling all item click from the starting.

Comment: use isEnabled() with position, get the position of clicked item first then check if the item is clicked then make this flase other wise true.

Comment: I used isEnabled() and based on some condition by checking position, I have solved my problem.